# Why no bullets appear on the screen when I press the spacebar

Tags: python

I created a simple game with a spaceship that is supposed to fire bullets when you press the spacebat. But when I press it , nothing seems to appear on the screen.

If you print the number on bullets ,they appear as numbers ,but they are invisible on the screen

I tried going over the code in the book again,but I found no mistakes.

What can I do to make the bullets visible?

here is the code : https://github.com/chip00/Game

there is no error message,the bullets just do not appear

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Post the actual segment of code which is meant to create the bullets

Comment: it is mainly the bullet file.But there are pieces of code related to the bullets in most files

Comment: Post the pertinent code snippets in the question

Comment: The files are not big and I didnt want to make a mess

Comment: I cant even post the code ,I have character restriction.

Comment: Post it in the question, not a comment. And not the whole thing, just relevant bits

Comment: def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):

        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen

        #create bullet rect at (0,0) and then set correct position
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
                                ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

        #store bullet's possition
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

Comment: def update(self):

        self.y -= self.speed_factor

        #update rect possition
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)

Comment: No, edit the question and embed the code, it's unreadable in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script to update the screen in game_functions.py should look like this instead:

```
def update_screen(ai_settings , screen, ship, bullets):

screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
ship.blitme()

for bullet in bullets.sprites():
    bullet.draw_bullet()

pygame.display.flip()
```

The display was updated before the bullets were added. Updating the screen should happen after all drawing has happened. In the original code the bullets were missing because it would draw in the following order:

- FRAME 1: fill screen -> draw ship -> update screen
- FRAME 2: draw bullets -> fill screen -> draw ship -> update screen
- ...

Comment: @ChiprianTutueanu please you can always choose his answer as best btw for further helps you can see the same project (Eric Matthes Alien Invasion) at github https://github.com/bryanlds/Alien-Invasion/blob/master/game_functions.py **in case you have problems in future**